# getting post data and creating session variable in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, session

hi I am new to wordpress. I have few problems fromlong while. What I am trying to do is..
 I have put some normal javascript code to send post data using AJAX..which is fine I have tested them out side wordpress but what I have to do is getting data in wordpress and storing themin wordpress session..a part of javascript code like

```
function purchase(img, price){
xmlHttp=CreateXmlHttpObject()
  if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
  return
  } 
  var url="http://www.example.com/purchase.php";
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=setTimeout(function(){stateChanged();}, 300)  ;
  xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlHttp.send("image="+img+"&price="+price);
}
```

so please help me..how I get this data in wordpress and most important how do I store them in wordpress session. does normal $_POST works in wordpress????

Comment: Why do not you try first. And post your errors here if you could not get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $_POST[] works in wordpress.
To set session add session_start() at the beginnning of file ie  after `<?php` line.
Then set session variable by - $_SESSION['variable_name'] = "variable value";
ex: `$_SESSION['my_num'] = 5;`

Here session variable my_num is set to 5. To access this variable use

```
echo $_SESSION['my_num'];
```